# How can I force my dedicated GPU to handle all applications or disable my integrated GPU?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, gpu

I'm a software developer and currently Electron, a library I'm using [lacks a feature to choose whether the dedicated GPU handles the dynamically generated executable](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9842) during development (each time you save a change, an executable is dynamically generated for quick testing.

So I can't just change Windows settings for this specific executable to use the desired GPU), so I'm wondering if there's a way to just force my dedicated (non CPU integrated) GPU to handle everything on my system. This isn't really a software question, the context just seems relevant.

How can I force my dedicated GPU to handle all applications or disable my integrated GPU?

Comment: You may or may not have that options in UEFI settings but also you should have the option to select by profile in the Nvidia's software.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?? my production exe also runs by default with the lower performing card. is there a way? a batch file you can create to force the other card maybe?

Answer (score -3):

From [pureinfotech:](https://pureinfotech.com/set-gpu-app-windows-10/)

> Starting with version 1803 (April 2018 Update) and later versions, Windows 10 features a new section in the Settings app, which also allows to specify the preferred graphics card for traditional desktop and Microsoft Store apps to improve system performance or battery life.
>
> To force an app to use a discrete GPU instead of the integrated adapter, or vice versa, to provide better system performance or battery life, use these steps:
>
> 1. Open Settings.
> 2. Click on System.
> 3. Click on Display.
> 4. Under “Multiple displays,” click the Advanced graphics settings link.
> 5. Select the kind of app you want to configured using the drop-down menu: (Classic app — these are your traditional Win32 desktop programs.) (Universal app — these are those app available through the Microsoft Store.)
> 6. If you select Classic app, you’ll need to click the Browse button to locate the “.exe” file to add the app. Otherwise, if you select the Universal app option, you’ll see a second drop-down menu to select the app.
> 7. Select the app you added from the list.
> 8. Click the Options button.
> 9. Set the graphics preference you want to use: (System default — this is always the default setting, and Windows 10 decide which GPU to use automatically. Power saving — runs the application on the GPU that uses the least power, which most of the time is your integrated graphics processor. High performance — runs the application on the most capable GPU, which is most of the time an external or discrete graphics processor.)
> 10. Click the Save button.
>
> Once you’ve configured the steps, the app you configured will use the graphics processor you specified optimizing battery life or performance the next time you launch it.

Comment: From [my question](https://superuser.com/questions/1439471/how-can-i-force-my-dedicated-gpu-to-handle-all-applications-or-disable-my-integr): `(each time you save a change, an executable is dynamically generated for quick testing, so I can't just change Windows settings for this specific executable to use the desired GPU)`

Comment: Doesn't work with premiere pro, which keeps using the integrated GPU.